# How to add the external file to C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I just want to add the external file in C# desktop application to store the queries. In that I want to add each query as string. And will take out of the file when needed.

1) How to add external file in C# desktop application.
2) How can i access the file from my application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, are these database queries, if they are then anyone that can access the file could modify the queries and run malicious against your DB, perhaps not the best idea ever

Comment: I will access the file from my application. I used to store the queries in one file and i will get the queries.  
Ex: string uname="select uname from u_tbl where u_id=101"

I will access the file to get the query by the variable uname.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options:

1. Add the file to the project and set the "Copy to Output Folder" option. Then make sure you deploy the file with the application.
2. Make the file an embedded resource. Then it becomes part of the exe and you don't have to deal with a separate file for deployment.

Comment: I will access the file from my application. I used to store the queries in one file and i will get the queries. Ex: string uname="select uname from u_tbl where u_id=101" I will access the file to get the query by the variable uname