# how to add external data files in c# and access them relatively

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have project in c# it already has some images and videos folders in its solution. I want to know how is it done. so for example i make a new folder to keep some files and i could access them just by their name and probably with folder name under which they are in project also keeping it consistent for debug/release version. I just want to add a text file in a folder say security and just access the file with relative path not absolute path. might be similar to this one but it doesn't help much.
[How to add the external file to C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660257/how-to-add-the-external-file-to-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your application will have to have those folders in the same directory as the `.exe`

From there you can read it like this :

```
// This will return all the files Path from that exist in that directory
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@".\[directoryName]\");

// From there you can use this line to read the content of a certain file
// In this example i'm reading the first file
// You can use a loop to loop through the files
// There are lot of ways on how to read from a file, leave that for you to find out
File.ReadAllLines(list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory) or [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo) classes. In my example I use DirectoryInfo. .NET Framework 4.5 added EnumerateFiles method which has superior performance over GetFiles (as in @ZohirSalak CeNa's answer) because it doesn't load all files from directory but lazily one-by-one.

```
static void ReadFolderFiles()
{
    // The parent folder of "my_folder" will be **exe**'s folder:
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo("my_folder\\sub_folder");
    // Or: DirectoryInfo("my_folder")
    foreach(FileInfo file in dir.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i have added a folder named security in project directory via visual studio project tree. now project starts in Debug mode and it tries to find this folder in project/bin/Debug/security and it doesn't get created there. how do i make it copy the folder there?

Comment: @user3003652 You added this folder only to your project. If you want it to automatically appear, you need to create one manually (in constructor or in `Loaded` event [if WPF] or in `Load` event [if WinForms]).